# Calculate Median in Multiple Rows

Tags: bash

I have a file name **numbers**, simply contain bunch random numbers

```
1     2     3
7     5     9
2     2     9
5     4     5
7     2     6
```

I have to create a script that find the median for each row, and here is my code:

```
while read -a row
do
  for i in "${row[@]}"
  do

    length=`expr ${#row[@]} % 2`
    if [ $length -ne 0 ] ; then
      mid=`expr ${#row[@]} / 2`
      echo ${row[middle]}
    elif [ $length -eq 0 ] ; then
      val1=`expr ${#row[@]} / 2`
      val2=`expr (${$row[@]} / 2) + 1`
      mid=`expr ($val1 + $val2) / 2`
      echo $mid
  done | sort -n
done < numbers
```

However this doesn't work, it shows error instead. What mistake did I do in this code? Also I still haven't figure out where is the proper way to place the `sort -n` since it needs to be sorted first before calculate the median, right?

Comment: You're using `echo ${row[middle]}` instead of `echo ${row[mid]}`. Also, `${$row[@]}` is invalid. You likely want `${#row[@]}` instead.

Comment: Do you know that `bash` can only do integer arithmetic?

Comment: Hi gniourf_gniourf, I made a typo in this thread, in my code it is `${#row[@]}`. Sorry about the typo!

Answer (score 1):

Bash can only do integer arithmetic, you need a tool like `bc` to compute the average:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -a n ; do
    n=($(IFS=$'\n' ; echo "${n[*]}" | sort -n))
    len=${#n[@]}
    if (( len % 2 )) ; then
        echo ${n[ len / 2 ]}
    else
        bc -l <<< "scale=1; (${n[ len / 2 - 1 ]} + ${n[ len / 2 ]}) / 2"
    fi
done
```

I'd probably reach for a higher level language, e.g. Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    my @n = sort { $a <=> $b } split;
    print @n % 2 ? $n[ @n / 2 ]
                 : ($n[ @n / 2 - 1 ] + $n[ @n / 2 ]) / 2,
          "\n";
}
```

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９: Depends on how you run the script.

Comment: Ah I see, no wonder I'm having a difficulties using bash only. I'll try this one into my script.

Comment: Hi Choroba, I've tried the code however why it prints 2,5,2,4,2 which is the value of the middle row instead of 2,7,2,5,6 (the median from each line)?

Comment: @coava: I'm getting `2 7 2 5 6` for both. The first must be run as `script.sh < input`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to awk it, for the fun of it.

Notice I don't use an `if` but fractions of indexes.

```
awk '{
  split($0,a)    # create array a from input line
  asort(a,b)     # sort array into array b (gnu awk specific)
  # add twice the median, or around the median and divide by 2
  print ( b[int(NF/2+0.7)] + b[int(NF/2+1.2)] )/2
}' numbers
```

Shortened (67 chars):

```
awk '{split($0,a);asort(a,b);print(b[int(NF/2+0.7)]+b[int(NF/2+1.2)])/2}' numbers
```

66 chars golf :-)

```
awk '{split($0,a);asort(a,b);$0=(b[int(NF/2+0.7)]+b[int(NF/2+1.2)])/2}1' numbers
```

Comment: for odd number of elements it can be squeezed further to `awk '{n=split($0,a)/2;asort(a,b);$0=b[n+.5]}1'`